# Django, bulk_create or bulk_update with manytomanyfield?

Tags: django

With the following models,

```
class Song(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Album(models.Model):

    songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song, through=AlbumSong)


class AlbumSong(models.Model):
    song = models.ForeginKey(song)
    album = models.ForeginKey(album)
```

I want to do `bulk_create` albums with songs (following code doesn't work because songs field can't be set as it is)

```
albums = [
    Album(
        songs=[1,2]
    ),
    Album(
        songs=[3,5]
    )
]

Album.objects.bulk_create(albums)
```

I also want to `bulk_update` with songs set to list of values

```
albums = Album.objects.some_filter()

for album in albums:
    album.songs = [1,2]


Album.objects.bulk_update(albums)
```

I can do `bulk_create` on `AlbumSong` through table, but it's harder with `bulk_update` where you might have to remove some songs from albums.
(you want to set songs to `[1, 2]` , you have to delete songs other than 1,2, if exsting albums have songs other than 1, 2)

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up doing deleting and modifying

- find all existing albums , and update them (`Album.objects.some_filter().update()`)
- find AllbumSongs where song is neither of `[1,2]` and delete them
- bulk_create AlbumSongs with `[1,2]` with ignore_conflicts=True